# How to parse data in list that contains JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, list

I want to get data inside list that contains `JSON` data:

```
my_list = [{"fruit": "banana"}, {"fruit": "apple"}, {"fruit": "orange"}]
```

Output:

```
banana
apple
orange
```

Comment: And what have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: The way you have presented it, you do *not* have JSON data. JSON data is always a string. What you have is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: As @RonaldAaronson said, you have list of dictionaries. However,...your json looks like this: `[ {"fruit" : "banana" }, {"fruit" : "apple"}, {"fruit" : "orange"}]`. Wouldn't be much nicer if you had your json structured like this: `{ "fruit" : [ "banana", "apple", "orange"] }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the list to String using json.dumps , then convert the string to json. Access the individual items.

```
import json
my_list = [{"fruit": "banana"}, {"fruit": "apple"}, {"fruit": "orange"}]
my_json_string = json.dumps(my_list)
data = json.loads(my_json_string)
for fruits_list in data:
    print(fruits_list["fruit"])
```

Output

```
banana
apple
orange
```

Comment: But why? I think the question was poorly asked, i.e. the list never *contained* JSON data. Now you have converted everything, including the list, to JSON just to convert it back to Python structures.

Answer (score 0):

I believe here's what you're looking for:

```
my_list = [{"fruit": "banana"}, {"fruit": "apple"}, {"fruit": "orange"}]
l = [v for e in my_list for k,v in e.items()]
print(' '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
banana apple orange
```

Comment: Thats right. But even simpler : `l = [v for e in my_list for v in e.values()]`

Comment: @RonaldAaronson  Agreed. If you don't care about the keys (which in this case is true), this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: But if you can't be sure there might be other keys besides 'fruit', which in that case you *do* care about the keys, then: `l = [e['fruit'] for e in my_list]`